# Writing a CSV from a dictionary where the keys are one row and the values are another row

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
mergedDict = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'g': '7', 'h': '8', 'i': '9', 'j': '10'}
```

I'd like to create CSV that has the following output:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

I tried to doing 'writerow' to print out each row, but I can't get an the right output that I'm looking for. Sometimes, it just prints out one key and one value but not the rest. Does any one have ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `csv` module.

```
with open('FileName.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer_ = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer_.writerow(mergedDict.keys())
    writer_.writerow(mergedDict.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
  mergedDict = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'g': '7', 'h': '8', 'i': '9', 'j': '10'}
  write = csv.writer(f)
  header = sorted(mergedDict.keys())
  write.writerows([header]+[[mergedDict[i] for i in header]])
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mergedDict = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'g': '7', 'h': '8', 'i': '9', 'j': '10'}
with open('file.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(', '.join(sorted(mergedDict.keys()))+'\n'+', '.join(sorted(mergedDict.values())))
```

Comment: This works great! Is the "sorted" part the part that allows an output in the order that I have in the mergedDict? When I used some of the other programs that were suggested above, the columns don't show up in the order that I was looking for (I was looking for how it is in the mergedDict a:1, b:2, c:3, etc). Your suggestion is the only one that gave me the order that I wanted.

Comment: Yes, it is the `sorted` part. Sorted sorts the list and returns the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you another option: CSVs and other tabular format are easy to deal with in `pandas`. If that's an option, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(mergedDict, index=range(1)).to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, we aren't allowed to use pandas for this particular project.